# How to auto run a single file program silently

Tags: windows-7, windows, deployment, autorun, silent-install

First of all, apology if this question has been already asked. I saw similar questions on the Internet but none of the answers work in my case.

I look after a call center with 50 odd PCs (running Windows 7) and around 90 staff members. Multiple shifts a day. Everyone sits there they want (if they are early enough) or where it's free ( if they aren't :) ). This causes me problems where deploying software, since in many cases I need to install software on each user on each PC. That's like 5000 installs.

Today I need to install and auto run a software for each user. In this case it is a single .exe file so I don't need to install it - simple copy is enough. To save me some time I thought I would copy this file into:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

on each PC. This will allow me to do only 50 installs (once on each PC) rather than for each user. This will also cause the program to auto run every time a user logs into the PC.

The problem I face is that when the program runs, it produces a confirmation dialog box asking whether to run the program or not. Users can click on "Run" with no problems; however, it is far from ideal for reasons I don't want to bore you with.

I want this software to auto run silently but I'm not sure how to do it. There is a checkbox on the dialog box saying "Always ask before opening this file". When I un-tick this and press "Run" it asks me for admin details. I put them in and it runs; however, when I log off, log back in next time, the windows still pops up.

How do I make the software to run silently? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks for your input everyone!

Screenshot of the message is below. Also, I can confirm  users do not have local admin permissions, and the software does not require admin permissions for the users to run.

[image]

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of the actual message you are receiving when the application runs. There are a few very similar messages, and the one you are seeing is important. Also, I’m guessing from your post that your users do not have local admin permissions, and the software does not require admin permissions for the users to run?

Comment: Hi Appleoddity, thanks for your efforts. I have updated the question.

Comment: @PiotrZurek If the said ".exe" can take arguments(options) from command line, there is always the chance it has a silent mode, so you could check that by executing it from cmd "your.exe /?" (-? , /help, -help , -h, /h, etc). Other way is  and copy it that way and add the execution on the TaskSchudler. Last method would be `C:\> Runas /profile /user:domain-or-pc\yoursisadminname your.exe` write that in a text editor and save it a ".bat"

Comment: Thanks to all who made an effort in responding to my query. In the end I figured it out myself. It appears that ticking the "Always ask before opening this file" box, as non-admin user, didn't do all; however, ticking that box as an admin user stopped the message from reappearing. Now the file is run silently (even in a non-admin user). I have replicated the error (and the fix) on other PCs, so the solution seems to be legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who made an effort in responding to my query. In the end I figured it out myself. :)

It appears that ticking the "Always ask before opening this file" box, as non-admin user, didn't do all; however, ticking that box as an admin user stopped the message from reappearing. Now the file is run silently (even in a non-admin user).

I have replicated the error (and the fix) on other PCs, so the solution seems to be legit.

Answer (score 0):

For this message, please see if you can unblock the file by modifying the file's properties.

Navigate to the folder that contains the file in question, then right-click the file, and click *Properties*.

Look for and check the box the says "Unblock" under the General tab, then apply the settings.

[image]

https://www.howtogeek.com/256303/how-to-unblock-a-file-from-windows-publisher-could-not-be-verified-warning/